# How to matching missing IDs?

Tags: r

I have a large table with 50000 obs. The following mimic the structure:

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
a <- c("A","B",NA,"D","E",NA,"G","H","I")
b <- c(11,2233,12,2,22,13,23,23,100)
c <- c(12,10,12,23,16,17,7,9,7)
df <- data.frame(ID ,a,b,c)
```

Where there are some missing values on the vector "a". However, I have some tables where the ID and the missing strings are included:

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
a <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I")

key <- data.frame(ID,a)
```

Is there a way to include the missing strings from key into the column a using the ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another options is to use `data.table`s fast *binary join* and *update by reference* capabilities

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df), ID)[key, a := i.a]
df
#    ID a    b  c
# 1:  1 A   11 12
# 2:  2 B 2233 10
# 3:  3 C   12 12
# 4:  4 D    2 23
# 5:  5 E   22 16
# 6:  6 F   13 17
# 7:  7 G   23  7
# 8:  8 H   23  9
# 9:  9 I  100  7
```

If you want to replace *only* the `NA`s (not *all* the joined cases), a bit more complicated implemintation will be

```
setkey(setDT(key), ID)
setkey(setDT(df), ID)[is.na(a), a := key[.SD, a]]
```

Comment: Hallo David, thank you for showing both ways. I know its difficult to explain without showing the original data, but both of your ways ran through without error and without replacing the `NA`

Comment: Do you have real `NA`s or just character `"NA"`? Either way, the first method should work in any case. It is also possible that no case in `key` is matching `df`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `match`; however, I would recommend that both your datasets are using `character`s instead of `factor`s to prevent headaches later on.

```
key$a <- as.character(key$a)
df$a <- as.character(df$a)

df$a[is.na(df$a)] <- key$a[match(df$ID[is.na(df$a)], key$ID)]
df
#   ID a    b  c
# 1  1 A   11 12
# 2  2 B 2233 10
# 3  3 C   12 12
# 4  4 D    2 23
# 5  5 E   22 16
# 6  6 F   13 17
# 7  7 G   23  7
# 8  8 H   23  9
# 9  9 I  100  7
```

Of course, you could always stick with `factor`s and factor the entire "ID" column and use the labels to replace the values in column "a"....

```
factor(df$ID, levels = key$ID, labels = key$a)
## [1] A B C D E F G H I
## Levels: A B C D E F G H I
```

Assign that to `df$a` and you're done....

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. Following your advice, I just get on my original data a vector as output with the lenght of my `NA` mixed with entries and `NA`

Answer (score 0):

Named vectors make nice lookup tables:

```
lookup <- a
names(lookup) <- as.character(ID)
```

lookup is now a named vector, you can access each value by lookup[ID] e.g. lookup["2"] (make sure the number is a character, not numeric)

```
## should give you a vector of a as required.
lookup[as.character(ID_from_big_table)]
```

Comment: Match seems to be faster on large vectors/data.frames.

Comment: I think this way is more readable than match, but yes speed probably important for big frames.